# why firebase didnt load node_modules files during host?

Tags: html, node.js, node-modules, firebase-hosting

in my html, i'm using this to link the boostrap file

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>`

I also tried this

`@import url("/node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css");`

I even try this for the javascript and its the same.

`<script  defer src="/node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"/>`

But both didnt even load at all? why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see two possible problems here:

1. You are using paths with a leading slash, which means "from root". Your paths should either be `./node_modules/etc` or `node_modules/etc`
2. Firebase host does not run `npm install` and does not fetch depencencies. And I don't think it should, actually. You should either copy the ressources that you're going to use to a directory next to your `html` files (i.e. `js` or `style`) and load them with a script tag (i.e. `href="./style/bootstrap.min.css` or simply load them via [any free CDN](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/getting-started/#download-cdn)